# Copying Iterator passed to constructor to vector

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I'm trying to copy values that are passed through the constructor inside a vector. Here is the code:

```
class Foo {

public:
    template<typename T>
    Foo(T begin, T end)
    {
        std::copy(begin, end, data.begin());        
    }

    void printVector()
    {
        cout << data.size();
    }
protected:
    std::vector<double> data;
};
```

And the main:

```
std::vector<double> data = {
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
};

Foo::Foo f(

    std::begin(data),
    std::begin(data)
);

f.printVector();
```

Could someone please explain why this does not work? Also, if I had a `std::vector<vector<double> > data` 2D vector, and, I passed in an iterator for the 2D vector, is it possible to copy this to a 2D vector?

Thanks

Comment: You should have given more details when you said "does not work". What happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, your vector data member has size `0`, so you cannot `std::copy` to it in the way you do. You should initialize the data member from the two iterators using the constructor initialization list:

```
template<typename T>
Foo(T begin, T end) : data(begin, end) {}
```

Second, you are not attempting to copy any elements. This is totally broken:

```
Foo::Foo f(
  std::begin(data),
  std::begin(data)
);
```

It should probably be

```
Foo f(std::begin(data), std::end(data));
```

Comment: I re-sized the vector: `data.resize(10);` and used the `back_inserter(data))` and This did not work.. Where could I be going wrong? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Thank you. But, how do I therefore access 'data' can I use: `std::begin(data)` etc.. inside of the constructor to pass it to a vector?

Comment: @user1326876 If you mean the `data` that is a data member of `Foo`, so yes, you can use it inside the `Foo` class. Unfortunately, you have two things called `data` in your code, which makes your questions unclear.

Comment: I have tried the following: `dataBase.reserve(10);
   std::copy(dataBase.begin(), dataBase.end(), std::back_inserter(dataBase));` (dataBase is named in the constructor differently now) and I have also tried: `dataBase.reserve(10);
   std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(dataBase));` and have does not work.. Sorry, but, where am I going wrong?

Comment: @user1326876 There is no point in calling it anyway. I gave you a solution that doesn't need any of that. Otherwise, I would say it doesn't work because `dataBase` has not been declared.

Answer (score 2):

You must allocate space, `vector::begin` doesn't do it for you. You may also use `push_back_inserter`.

Additionally, use give `std::begin(data)` twice to `Foo`.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
Foo::Foo f(

    std::begin(data),
    std::begin(data)
);
```

You mean

```
Foo::Foo f(

    std::begin(data),
    std::end(data)  //<- note the change
);
```

Also, you have not made space for the destination of the copy in the constructor, so you need to use a `back_inserter`

```
std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(data));
```